# Alphabetically sorting a backbone collection using a key

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection that needs to be sorted by on a particular key ('display'), I know that backbone has a default comparator that is not defined by default, but I am at a loss of how to actually implement it

```
 var listCollection = new Backbone.Collection(rebuiltArray.map(function(text){
  return {
    attribute: text,
    displayNames: displayNames[text]
  };

 }));
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
 var ListCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     comparator: 'displayNames'
 });

 var listCollection = new ListCollection(rebuiltArray.map(function(text){
    return {
        attribute: text,
        displayNames: displayNames[text]
    };
 }));
```

Comment: So you can define a comparator without having to define a function?

Comment: Comparator functions are used only if you have a special sorting criteria and not natural sorting one.